# Call a PHP script when an option is selected from a select element in HTML

Tags: php, html

At the moment I have the following markup code on my website:

```
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
```

I want to have a PHP script in the same directory as my webpage fire when I select a particular option. How would I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: why don't you use ajax?

Comment: There are so many different ways to do this that it's a little hard to give you just one answer. You could wrap it in a form and use POST or you could use AJAX...

Comment: [A-J-A-X](https://i.imgflip.com/84wln.jpg)

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have mentioned that I don't have a hell of a lot of experience with web development (mainly an application developer) so I am liable to say stupid things at times :P

Answer (score 2):

call a ajax on change of select like this

```
<select onchange="javascript:callAjax(this.value);">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<script>
function callAjax(sel_opt)
{
   var url = "your_php_file.php?select_option="+sel_opt;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
            // put your result where ever you want
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);

    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**your_php_file.php**

```
<?php

// your code

?>
```

Comment: Sorry to the above comments, I mainly do application programming and I have just started doing a lot more web programming work, so I wasn't really aware of Ajax. New experiences everywhere :P

Answer (score 1):

Do an Ajax call. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)'s an example. hope this helps to understand.

cheers!